# Rebase current branch to a previous commit version in GIT

Tags: git

I am in my current branch say "feature/Sprint2"
With the following commits:

1. c1004
2. c1003
3. c1002
4. c1001
5. c1000

Now i want to update my current branch to c1002 and update the current branch..after which the commits will look like:

1. c1002
2. c1001
3. c1000

Whats the commands ?

Comment: You seem to want to *drop* the two most recent commits, which I wouldn't describe as an "update" or "rebase" but which can be done with `git reset HEAD~2 --hard`.

Comment: He didn’t specify whether or not he wants to keep the code so telling him to do a hard reset may not get him to his desired goal in this situation. You also didn’t tell him what that argument does which may have unintended effects.

Comment: I want to discard all commits prior to c1002

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn’t tell me your situation I will consider a couple cases and give you advice on what to do in those cases.

Case 1: You want to keep the code but drop the commits

```
git rebase -i <c1001 commit hash> 
<change the pick to fixup for c1003 and c1004>
<save your text editor> 
git push -f origin feature/Sprint2
```

Case 2: You don't want to keep the commits or the code

```
git reset --hard <c1002 commit hash>
git push -f origin feature/Sprint2
```

Comment: I want to discard all commits prior to c1002

Comment: In your post you said you wanted to discard all commits *after* c1002. Which one is it?

Comment: want to discard c1004, c1003

Comment: Then the second set of commands I gave you will achieve this.